# Prove that if $\langle A_1, ..., A_k \rangle = M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$, then $ \langle A_1^t, ..., A_k^t \rangle = M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{F})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that $$\langle A_1, ..., A_k \rangle = M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F}) \Longrightarrow \langle A_1^t, ..., A_k^t \rangle = M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{F})$$ By definition, $S=\{A_1, ..., A_k\}$ is subset of the minor vector subspace $W$ where $W=\cap \{W_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $W_i \subseteq V$. We say that $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F}) = \langle S \rangle$ is the vector space generated by $S$.

Note: By definition of $W$, $$W \subseteq \{W_i\}_{i\in I} \Longrightarrow S \subseteq \{W_i\}_{i\in I}$$

Edit. I'm not sure this is true, but I'm sure that the one for $n \times n$ is true...

Comment: I found the solution for $n \times n$ matrix. Let $A \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{F})$, then $A^t \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{F})$. As $\langle S \rangle$ is the set of all linear combinations of $S$, $\exists a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{\mathbb{F}}$ s.t. $a_1 A_1 + a_2 A_2 + ... + a_n A_n = A^t$ which implies that $(a_1 A_1 + a_2 A_2 + ... + a_n A_n)^t = (A^t)^t$ which again implies that $a_1 A_1^t + a_2 A_2^t + ... + a_n A_n^t = A$. Therefore, $\langle A_1^t,..., A_k^t \rangle$ generates $M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: Why do you believe that this solution fails in the general case?

Comment: @BenGrossmann because if $A\in M_{n \times n}$,  $A^t\in M_{n \times n}$ and we can proceed. But if $A\in M_{m \times n}$,  $A^t\in M_{n \times m}$ and we cannot proceed because it is not posible to generate $A^t \in M_{n \times m}$ with $A_1, ..., A_k \in  M_{m \times n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for the square case can be extended to the general case.

> Let $A \in M_{n \times m}(\Bbb F)$, then $A^T \in M_{m \times n}(\Bbb F)$. Because $\langle A_1,\dots,A_k\rangle = M_{m \times n}(\Bbb F)$, there exist coefficients $a_i$ (for $i = 1,\dots,k$) such that $a_1 A_1 + \cdots + a_k A_k = A^T$. By the linearity of the transpose, we have $a_1 A_1^T + \cdots + a_k A_k^T = A^{TT} = A$. Thus, the arbitrary matrix $A \in M_{n \times m}(\Bbb F)$ is an element of $\langle A_1^T,\dots,A_k^T \rangle$. That is, we have $\langle A_1^T, \dots, A_k^T \rangle = M_{n\times m}(\Bbb F)$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: I was not sure about this, but if we are now two thinking about the same solution, then it may be correct. Thanks man!